# Display view on my scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to add three views to a scrollview. These views have to be next to one another like Snapchat. However, when I launch my app on another device which is another size, the views don't adapt. Does someone know how can I resolve this problem?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let MainEuroView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
let TicketEuroView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TicketViewController") as! TicketViewController
let ProfilView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilViewController") as! ProfilViewController

var TicketViewFrame : CGRect = TicketView.view.frame
TicketViewFrame.origin.x = 0
TicketView.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
TicketView.view.frame = TicketViewFrame

var MainViewFrame : CGRect = MainView.view.frame
MainViewFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
MainView.view.frame = MainViewFrame

var ProfilViewFrame : CGRect = ProfilView.view.frame
ProfilViewFrame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
ProfilView.view.frame = ProfilViewFrame

self.addChildViewController(TicketView)
self.main_Scroll_View.addSubview(TicketView.view)
TicketView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

self.addChildViewController(MainView)
self.main_Scroll_View.addSubview(MainView.view)
MainView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

self.addChildViewController(ProfilView)
self.main_Scroll_View.addSubview(ProfilView.view)
ProfilView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

self.main_Scroll_View.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to move the frame adjustment to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, you usually don't have the view frame during `viewDidLoad`, but instead get the frame of the view in the storyboard, e.g.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    var TicketViewFrame : CGRect = TicketView.view.frame
    TicketViewFrame.origin.x = 0
    TicketView.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    TicketView.view.frame = TicketViewFrame

    var MainViewFrame : CGRect = MainView.view.frame
    MainViewFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    MainView.view.frame = MainViewFrame

    var ProfilViewFrame : CGRect = ProfilView.view.frame
    ProfilViewFrame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
    ProfilView.view.frame = ProfilViewFrame
}
```

A better fix would be to implement autolayout which will do this automatically for you.